# How to install and use scanlogd

Tags: ports

I want to install and run scanlogd from my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I am able to install and run it with `apt-get install scanlogd` and it works fine.

But I am not able to change the parameters like log count threshold or max length of a message.

I also want to sweep with other parameters inside the source code. I couldn't make it run with a dummy user named scanlogd.

It also didn't work when I add an empty directory in /var/empty where scanlogd is chrooting.

Comment: When asking for troubleshooting help, saying "it doesn't work" is not at all helpful. What happens? Is there any output or messages? Please copy/paste the text of the output and use the code formatting tool. You also don't mention if you have looked up the documentation or what help from the documentation you have tried. Or have you just installed and tried to run it without reading the manual?

Answer (score 1):

> But i am not able to change the parameters like log count threshold or
> max length of a message

Scanlogd does not accept command line or configuration file changes to these parameters.  In order to change them, you would need to modify the source code (available [here](https://www.openwall.com/scanlogd/)) and compile a custom copy of scanlogd.

> But i am not able to change the parameters like log count threshold or
> max length of a message
>
> I also want to sweep with other parameters inside the source code.

Configuration of scan parameters is found in param.h, for example:

```
/*
 * Port scan detection thresholds: at least COUNT ports need to be scanned
 * from the same source, with no longer than DELAY seconds between ports.
 */
#define SCAN_MIN_COUNT          7
#define SCAN_MAX_COUNT          (SCAN_MIN_COUNT * PORT_WEIGHT_PRIV)
#define SCAN_WEIGHT_THRESHOLD       SCAN_MAX_COUNT
#define SCAN_DELAY_THRESHOLD        3
```

and

```
/*
 * Log line length limit, such as to fit into one SMS message. #undef this
 * for no limit.
 */
#define LOG_MAX_LENGTH          (160 - 40)
```

> I couldn't make it run with a dummy user named scanlogd.

It is designed to drop root privileges and run as scanlogd.  Any attempt to simply run as scanlogd would fail due to permissions needed to listen to network interfaces, and be unnecessary as well.

```
/* We can drop root now */
#ifdef SCANLOGD_USER
    drop_root();
#endif
```

> It also didn't work when I add an empty directory in /var/empty where
> scanlogd is chrooting.

Nothing in the code to indicate why that would happen, unless you changed the permissions on /var/empty in the process...

```
/*
 * An empty directory to chroot to.  The directory and its parent directories
 * must not be writable by anyone but root.
 */
#define SCANLOGD_CHROOT         "/var/empty"
```

> Also a recommendation about any port scan detection tool that I may
> dive into it will be appreciated.

Scanlogd is pretty much the original port scan detector, but if you're looking for others, search for `github port scan detect` to find a few.  I think scanlogd is a good one to dive into because of its simple, well commented, and well laid out source code.